# Suffficent condition for a semigroup to be group

Tags: abstract-algebra

How can I prove a semi-group is a group if for every $$a\in S$$ there exists a unique $$b \in s$$ such that $$aba=a$$
A semigroup is a structure with a binary associative operation.

Answer (score 2):

As a hint, show that there exists a unique idempotent element in $S$: $\exists! x\in S, x^2=x$. From there you can show that $S$ has a left identity and every element has a left inverse.

You may find a complete solution at [this](https://books.google.com.tr/books?id=1nahrqDT56QC&pg=PA227&lpg=PA227&dq=a+semi+group+such+that+aba+%3D+a+is+a+group&source=bl&ots=PXp4u7hyDz&sig=ACfU3U0JJZoEU6zNd68ZsZ5S0ywxlw_flw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj90fS6qJDqAhX-UhUIHdduBEEQ6AEwAXoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=a%20semi%20group%20such%20that%20aba%20%3D%20a%20is%20a%20group&f=false) document (Algebra-I: A Basic Course in Abstract Algebra, by Rajendra Kumar Sharma, page 226).